# How to prefix <title> in tex4ht in split chapters?

Tags: tex4ht, make4ht

I am trying to get `tex4ht` to add a prefix to the `<title>` tags of split chapters.

Using the following `make4ht` config file:

```
\Preamble{xhtml,ext=html,charset="utf-8"}
\Configure{TITLE+}{Some Author | Book Title}
\begin{document}
\EndPreamble
```

With the following TeX file:

```
\documentclass[openright,a5paper]{scrbook}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}

\title{Some Book}
\subtitle{A novel}
\author{Some Author}

\begin{document}

\maketitle{}
\tableofcontents{}

\chapter{Chapter One}
\chapter{Chapter Two}

\end{document}
```

Compiling via:

```
make4ht --config make4ht.cfg --utf8 book.tex "2,sec-filename,nominitoc,sections+"
```

I end up with the main `.html` containing a nice title (`Some Author | Book Title`), as expected. However, the `<title>` tags of the chapter `.html` files contain:

```
 1 Chapter One
 2 Chapter Two
```

I would like the chapter pages to be titled (for easier bookmarking and SEO):

```
Some Author | Book Title | 1 Chapter One
Some Author | Book Title | 2 Chapter Two
```

How can I add this prefix? It seems the `TITLE+` configuration knob only applies to the main file.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Titles for pages broken on sectioning commands can be set using `\Configure{<cmd>TITLE+}{title contets}`. As you broke your document on chapters, you can use `chapterTITLE+`. You will probably also want to support `\chapter*`. In this case, add also the `likechapterTITLE+`:

```
\Preamble{xhtml,ext=html,charset="utf-8"}
\Configure{TITLE+}{Some Author | Book Title}
\Configure{chapterTITLE+}{Some Author | Book Title | \thechapter\space#1}
\Configure{likechapterTITLE+}{Some Author | Book Title | #1}
\begin{document}
\EndPreamble
```

The HTML file for chapter one now looks like this:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html> 
<html lang='en-US' xml:lang='en-US'> 
<head><title>Some Author | Book Title | 1 Chapter One</title> 
<meta charset='utf-8' />
```

Comment: Thanks, this is brillant! Works like a charm :-).
Is it also possible to include the chaper number in the title for the chapters?

Comment: @OliverFreyermuth sure, see my edit

Comment: Works perfectly :-). I already upvoted your reply and accepted it as answer, the vote may only arrive once I have collected enough reputation here. Thanks again!